# Salesforce "Knowledgeable People" component not showing data in community salesforce

Tags: community, chatter, feeditem, component

I have dragged the "Knowledgeable People" component on the topic detail page and configured it as per the guidelines given in the documentation. But the data is not getting shown in the community. I am unable to find the reason behind this. I even added the hardcoded id in the Topic ID property but even then it's not showing data for that particular topic. One other thing I noticed is that by inspecting the component I am seeing the message "Invalid Topic Id". Can someone help me to fix this issue?